# Can Spring MVC controller set the URL to be shown in browser?

Tags: spring-mvc, url-mapping

We have a Spring MVC Controller method which servers the url pattern /hello/{userName} .

```
@RequestMapping("/hello/{userName}")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(@PathVariable("userName") String productId) {  
        String message = "HELLO"+userName;  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
    }
```

Here when we request /hello/Tom ,hellopage.html will be servered with URL in the browser http://localhost:8080/myApp/hello/Tom

We would need the URL to be http://localhost:8080/myApp/Tom .Is there any way I can set the URL to be shown in the browser when returning from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that using `redirect`. Write two controllers:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello/{userName}")  
public string helloWorld(@PathVariable("userName") String userName, Model model) {  
    String message = "HELLO" + userName;  
    model.addAttribute("message", message);
    return "redirect:" + userName;
}  

@RequestMapping("/{userName}")  
public ModelAndView userHello((@ModelAttribute("message") String message)) {    
    return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is already a controller with "/{myString}" serving a different functionality. So I cannot use  "/{userName}" again. My intention is to show the URL's cleaner/simpler although they have long request mappings.

Comment: Of course mapping to "/{userName}" is not appropriate. and like you said it was an example which you can generally use for this intention.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also use tuckey url-rewrite for this: http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

This allows Apache mod_rewrite functionality in Tomcat through the use of a filter, and you wouldn't have to write two controllers for everything.